# How to edit the People (users admin view) to include filter by user name?

Tags: users

I want my admins to be able to search through the admin users view by the user name. I have a site with a lot of users and periodically the admins want to be able to check on various user fields. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot easily alter admin/people page but you can add a new tab to it using Views.
Create a custom View page that uses users as base table and expose user:name as a filter. Set its menu to a tab under admin/people and give access based on role or "administer users" permission.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the [Administration Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views):

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for
>   superior usability.
>
> Features
>
> - Filter all administrative views via AJAX.
> - Perform any kind of bulk/mass operations on items in administrative views.
> - Filter content by title, node type, author, published status, and/or vocabulary.
> - Filter comments by title, author, node title, or published status.
> - Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user roles.
>
> *Note: If you are upgrading from an older version of Administration views and the default views have been overridden (saved in the
>   database) you could encounter issues or not see any new changes unless
>   you revert these views, so the default in-code views are used. This
>   can be done in the views UI listing or using drush (drush cter
>   views_view --module=admin_views)

By default it has a specific users view, but since it is a view, you can modify it.

Comment: Note that in Drupal 8+ this functionality is in Core. Also, see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1823450